# Dividing n-bit binary integers

Tags: c++, pseudocode

Was wondering if anyone could help me with creating a pseudocode for how to go about dividing n-bit binary integers. Here is what I'm thinking could possibly work right now, could someone correct this if I'm wrong:

```
divide (x,y)
     if x=0: return (0,0) //(quotient, remainder)
     (q,r) = divide(floor(x/2), y)

     q=2q, r=2r
     if x is odd: r = r+1

     if r >= y: r = r-y, q = q+1
          return (q,r)
```

Would you guys say that this general pseudocode algorithm would accomplish the intended task of dividing n-bit numbers or am I missing something in my psuedocode before I start coding up something that's wrong?

Comment: coding up something that is wrong can sometimes help you work out where and why it is wrong. I do a lot of learning simply via debugging

Comment: also, due to the recursive nature of your program, will will only work  for values of 'n' where your stack doesn't get full :-)

Comment: You could probably save a lot of useless iterations by changing your termination condition to: if x < y: return (0, x).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments! I actually ended up forgetting that I asked this question, and just now re-checking, however I've managed to figure out how to not only get the psuedo-code but the program I was writing. Thanks for the tips though everyone, and Fuzz what you mentioned is indeed correct, I was at the time simply looking for opinions and seeing what people may suggest since I was at the starting stages of creating my program. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other then the obvious stuff (not checking for division by zero, not handling negative numbers), it seems to be working. I convinced myself by just applying this to base-10 numbers.